# how to run IntelliJ IDEA with JetBrains Runtime

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I'm trying to activate **Ligatures** a new feather in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 by following the instructions in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKCKwI-bfG0) but there are missing fonts and when using 64 version I get this hint.

> The JRE you are running IntelliJ IDEA with might have functional and performance issues related to ligatures support. To avoid such issues, run IntelliJ IDEA with JetBrains Runtime.

this is the fonts list [image]

how can I make this feather work?

[image]

Comment: The message shown on your screenshot has a link in it. Have you tried clicking the link and reading the information there? Hint: it contains the answer to your question.

Comment: yes, and it takes me to another page https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under
but the instructions are not clear, and when I tried to follow them nothing work.

Comment: What exactly did you try? As the linked documents say, if you want to run IDEA under a 64-bit JDK, you need to download it from https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/ . Have you done that?

Comment: I have tried this also and it took me to this link https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/openjdk8-windows-x64
but I can't download it, it says : No direct downloads selected for this package.

and I can't even make it work on 32-bit.

Comment: I also have defined user variable IDEA_JDK pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2\jre but also nothing

Comment: What problems exactly did you see with the 32-bit version? What do you mean by "there are missing fonts"? IntelliJ IDEA does not bundle any fonts; you need to install fonts with ligature support separately.

Comment: I have updated my question, and how can find I install fonts that support ligature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe a bit late to answer this. Recently ran into same issue, googling around came across this post. After while did figure out how to do it properly.

There is no installer but there is tar/gzip file for windows under files tab in bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/

- for windows 64 bit https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/openjdk8-windows-x64#files
  [ set me up button in the page is very misleading though..]

Once you download and extracted the JetBrains Runtime, add environment IDEA_JDK variable with path of runtime environment. Close the ide and start again, and you are good to go.

- for 64bit environment variable will be like `IDEA_JDK_64=c:/intellji-jdk/`

hint: IDEA_JDK for 32 bit idea.exe and IDEA_JDK_64 for 64 bit idea64.exe

As for the fira code font , they are in github https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode. Pull the latest to your PC via git or simply download the repo.

- For windows install the ttf fonts in distr folder [ all the fonts are under distr folder ].

Comment: What I did was to download https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/download_file?file_path=jbre8u112b724.6_windows_x64.tar.gz (`jbre` for JetBrains RunTime) for Windows 10 64-bit and move the contents to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\jre\jre`. I also backed up the original `jre` directory beforehand.

Comment: well that is too much of hassle if you ask me.
Its better to keep the intellij jdk separate from actual intellij idea installation. its easy to switch version of jdk or versions of intellij idea itself.
But in the end what ever get the job done for you, go with it.

Comment: True. I've done this also in sight of 2017.1 being the next release supporting the new runtime by default so I don't care if it gets deleted. *fingerscrossed*

Answer (score 2):

To switch the Java runtime used to run IntelliJ IDEA:

- On the Help menu, click Find Action, or press `Ctrl+Shift+A`.
- Find and select the `Switch Boot JDK` action.
- Select the desired JDK and click OK.

More details [Tuning IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem on ubuntu and followed [these instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) to resolve it. The JB SDK Bintray downloader allows you to manage JetBrains SDKs from within the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall Intellij IDE and reinstall again, it will ask you whether you need to install Jetbrains Runtime or not.

[Jetbrains Runtime Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cmjB.png)