# Font is installed but doesn't show in the menu of JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, ligature

I have updated IntelliJ IDEA recently (I have the latest possible version and build at the moment - see at the bottom) and since then my previously well chosen font with ligatures doesn't show anymore (I don't remember its name). Previously the fonts were provided in a menu, 5-6 of them and you would choose one within the IDE, but now there are a lot of fonts to choose from which I guess are taken from the system.

However, I followed these instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452701/how-to-run-intellij-idea-with-jetbrains-runtime) but still the font is not showing in the menu.
I have installed the font Fira Code (all available .ttf files: Bold, Light, Medium, Regular and Retina) on Windows, so e.g. it is available in Microsoft Word:  
[image: font available in Microsoft Word]

but even after restart it is not available in IntelliJ IDEA: 
[image: font not available in IntelliJ IDEA]
Any suggestion how to fix this?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
Runtime version: 11-ea+125 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Did you use "Install for all users" option (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/) when installed font?

Comment: No, thank you. That was the reason... I contacted with JetBrains support and yes they said it must be installed as an Administrator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The font must be installed as an Administrator (install for all users option).

You do this by opening the context menu of the font file, then click "Install for all users".

[image]